# package structure for a class that contains only constants

Tags: java, static, package

I have a realy simple class that contains only constants:

```
public class AppData {

    public static long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000L;

}
```

my question is in which package should I place the class and what should be the name of this package?

For example...
Activities are placed in:

```
de.appname.ui.activities
```

domain classes in:

```
de.appname.model
```

a class that contains only static informations:

```
(???)
```

I know it's a design question and I need you suggestion.

Best regards

Stefan

Comment: Opinion based question.

Comment: Package de.appname.utility or de.appname.common. Package name should make sense that's it for example static data is utilized commonly by all classes so you can put it in de.appname.common.

Comment: Maybe `... .conf` or `... .data`. A minor criticism: (1) you are aware that imported constants loose their `import`  as the they are filled in in the class. Hence you need a `clean build` whenever a constant is changed. A .properties resource bundle would sometimes be better. (2) the class is coupling diverse usage by other classes. And lead to more recompilation than is really necessary, especially if you do clean first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep this class under
 
`de.appname.util` or `de.appname.utility`
 
because all the constants will be utilized by other classes.

Comment: util is the right approach. thx a lot